# how can i update my ms sql server database from android directly without web services(RESTFULapi)

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio

i have tried to insert data into my db (on hosting) directly and idid it easily by the sqlcommand (insert into values....etc) when i tried to do the same with the update statement its not working .. why??

```
btnpunchin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd _ HH:mm:ss");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());


            try {

                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "there is something wrong ";
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(attendance.this, "Punch-in successful!!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Statement st = con.createStatement();

                  st.executeUpdate("UPDATE att" +
                          "SET name='yo' WHERE id= 404340 );");


                          st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO att " +
                          "VALUES ('3'  , '"+ currentDateandTime+"' , '4002' , GETDATE() )");
                          con.close();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }



        }
    });
```

Comment: "Not working" is kind of a useless statement in debugging. _What_ isn't working, and what's the error?

Comment: @TheWanderer nothing happen and the db is not updated

Comment: I notice that your first `executeUpdate()` is missing a space between `att` and `SET`, so the command is coming out to be `UPDATE attSET ...`.